# how to pass value from view to controller in web2py

Tags: model-view-controller, web2py

I want to insert the value of `lang` to mysql table. How to pass the value of `lang` to controller

```
view
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test(it)
    {
        var lang=it.value;
    }
</script>
<form>
<p>language
<select id="select"  onchange="test(this)">
  <option value ="0">c</option>
  <option value ="1">cc</option>
  <option value="2">pas</option>
  <option value="3">java</option>
  <option value ="4">rb</option>
</select>
</p>
</form>

conteoller
def problem(lang):
{
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

web2py doesn't work quite like that. Before proceeding, I suggest you read some of the [introductory documenation](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/03/overview) as well as the documentation on [forms](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#FORM).

If you submit a form to a web2py URL, the function that handles that URL can access the form variables in `request.vars` (also, `request.post_vars` if submitted via POST and `request.get_vars` if submitted via GET). In the case of your code, you would need to add a "name" attribute with the value "lang" to the `<select>` element, in which case, the receiving action could access the value via `request.vars.lang`. You controller action itself should not take any arguments.

Instead, though, you might find it easier to use web2py's built in forms functionality as noted above.